# Using views in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm running an SSIS package on the the view FilteredAccount. It takes a very long time to cache lookup data from this source, often around 15 minutes for the number of accounts we have. I ran the same package on the Account view and it completed in ~3 minutes.

I'm trying to understand whether using the unfiltered views is supported by MS in this case because the decrease in run time is amazing between the two. Looking in MSDN for an answer has been frustrating, since "views" and "filtered views" are almost noise words when it comes to CRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are differences between Views and FilteredViews:

1. FilteredViews available for any user. Views available only for users with Sys Admin privileges.
2. FilteredViews contains logic that returns data that is available for user that asks for a data (business units, sharing, e.t.c.).
3. FilteredViews return Label fields for every Lookup, OptionSet (that means additional joins on other tables) and converts all datetime fields to local time of user that asks data. Views return data as it is is in database.

So. My suggestion based on my experience. Forget about don't read data from Views bla-bla-bla. You can read data from Views without any problems.

Good luck.

Comment: Just to clarify, using unfiltered views is __NOT__ supported by Microsoft so you are technically outside of support. If in the next update they change the view definitions, or even eliminate them, it would not be considered a bug. That said, I agree with Andrii that if you need them for performance you should use them - you can always switch to Filtered Views if you had to down the road b/c they use the same field definitions.